# Calling Functions from Main

Tags: c, function, function-call

```
#include <stdio.h>



int function()
{
    printf("Hello World");


}

int main()
{
    function;
    return 0;
}
```

new to coding. This code compiles but doesnt work as intended. Any thoughts?

Comment: `function;` -> `function();`.

Comment: @user3386109 I believe it. This site should be optimized to handle inevitable questions that will be asked like wolfram alpha or some other calculator in the editing section before the question gets posted. I bet another question like this will get asked in the next 12 hours too.

Comment: @ThomFork Automated duplicate recognition would be a fun project to work on. I'm sure that at least one person at SO is thinking about it.

Comment: Take the habit to request the compiler to show all warnings (gcc: `-Wall`), gcc would say *warning: statement with no effect*